# Laptop keeps logging out after being in suspend mode in 16.10

Tags: dual-boot, suspend, 16.10

First of all I'm using Ubuntu 16.10 with gnome shell 3 alongside Windows 8.1 and a grub partition.

After closing the screen of my laptop, Ubuntu goes into suspend mode (I mean I think, how could I verify if it's suspend mode or hibernate mode? Cannot see that in the settings.). Everything seems fine until I press a random key, the computer turns on and asks me to log in, I do it, and then after about 10 seconds it logs out.

If I log in again, it logs out again after about 10 seconds, and it does that over and over until I shut it down manually and reboot.

I've looked at [this link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/587136) but it didn't help me.

EDIT: Here is my .xsession-errors.old (apparently no warnings or errors)

> dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
>   dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DISPLAY=:0
>   dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XAUTHORITY=/home/thuranos/.Xauthority
>   openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
>   cannot connect to braille devices daemon brltty at :0
>   dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge
>   dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
>   dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_LINUX_ACCESSIBILITY_ALWAYS_ON=1
>   dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_PAPER=fr_FR.UTF-8
>   dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_ADDRESS=fr_FR.UTF-8
>   dbus-update-activation-environment: setting CLUTTER_IM_MODULE=xim
>   dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR=/var/lib/lightdm-data/thuranos
>   dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_MONETARY=fr_FR.UTF-8
>   dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SHELL=/usr/bin/zsh
>   dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_LINUX_ACCESSIBILITY_ALWAYS_ON=1
>   dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_NUMERIC=fr_FR.UTF-8
>   dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge
>   dbus-update-activation-environment: setting USER=thuranos
>   dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
>   dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_TELEPHONE=fr_FR.UTF-8
>   dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_SESSION_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0
>   dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_SEAT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
>   dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DEFAULTS_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/gnome.default.path
>   dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-gnome:/usr/share/upstart/xdg:/etc/xdg
>   dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PATH=/home/thuranos/bin:/home/thuranos/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
>   dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DESKTOP_SESSION=gnome
>   dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_IM_MODULE=ibus
>   dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=appmenu-qt5
>   dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_IDENTIFICATION=fr_FR.UTF-8
>   dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PWD=/home/thuranos
>   dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11
>   dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
>   dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LANG=en_US.UTF-8
>   dbus-update-activation-environment: setting MANDATORY_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/gnome.mandatory.path
>   dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GDM_LANG=en_US
>   dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_MEASUREMENT=fr_FR.UTF-8
>   dbus-update-activation-environment: setting IM_CONFIG_PHASE=1
>   dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GDMSESSION=gnome
>   dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK2_MODULES=overlay-scrollbar
>   dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SHLVL=1
>   dbus-update-activation-environment: setting HOME=/home/thuranos
>   dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LANGUAGE=en_US
>   dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=gnome
>   dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LOGNAME=thuranos
>   dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT4_IM_MODULE=xim
>   dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
>   dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
>   dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DISPLAY=:0
>   dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
>   dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus
>   dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME
>   dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_TIME=fr_FR.UTF-8
>   dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_NAME=fr_FR.UTF-8
>   dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XAUTHORITY=/home/thuranos/.Xauthority
>   dbus-update-activation-environment: setting _=/usr/bin/dbus-update-activation-environment
>   upstart: click-user-hooks main process (3707) terminated with status 1
>   upstart: dbus main process (3703) killed by TERM signal
>   upstart: url-dispatcher main process (3708) killed by TERM signal
>   upstart: gnome-session (GNOME) main process (3885) killed by HUP signal
>   upstart: window-stack-bridge main process (3717) killed by HUP signal
>   upstart: gnome-settings-daemon main process (3877) killed by HUP signal

Comment: Main thing to check: in your home `.xsession_errors` It wil show the error you need to investigate.

Comment: I edited the post with the .xsession_errors, there's no warning or errors.